# Does the dart code work incorrectly when it is launched via 'pub serve'?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I have found some issue when I launch my polymer project by using `pub serve`.

In the code bellow the countChanged method is never called. It is works if I run this code via Dart Editor.

```dart
@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @published int count = 0;

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created() {
  }

  countChanged() {
    window.alert(count.toString());
  }

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

see also https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17507

note: a compiled js code works fine..

Comment: Both in Dartium or do you use `pub serve` to show it in another browser?

Comment: I use pub serve in Dartium. the compiled code works correctly in other browsers.

Comment: Fixed in polymer 0.11.0+5. see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17507

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Code Issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17507) relating to this issue ha a comment suggesting this code now works. It was likely a bug that was since fixed!